# node-quickbooks Express Sessions oAuth

Tags: node.js, oauth, quickbooks-online

I'm testing the Intuit OAuth2.0-demo for nodejs. [link](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/OAuth2.0-demo-nodejs)

The demo uses the node-quickbooks package within an Express server. The demo works fine but I have a question more about the general flow "best-practice" for a multi user setup.

For example:

You have your own web application that supports many users. The users login to your web application and decide to grant your web application access to Quickbooks.

How would i properly handle multiple users?

Currently, when I authorize the oAuth connection between the web app "demo" and Quickbooks the auth token is stored server-side.

The Express session is not unique to the specific logged in user on the demo web app. When I connect from different devices to my local demo web app they are all using the previously server-side stored auth token.

What is best practice for multiple users?

Answer (score 0):

The demo provided from Intuit was extremely helpful but it did not provide any additional code in the boilerplate for maintaining multiple users and properly storing the access_token / refresh_token / realmId inside a storage (such as Mongo). I ended up merging this demo project with a boilerplate Passport local strategy that uses mongo. I updated the mongoose model to store the Quickbooks Online tokens. This way when the user logs into my webapp via Passport we can just pull the tokens that are associated to there user account inside mongo.

I will probably make a repo for this since I think it can be helpful to others. For now, if anyone ends up finding this thread and has any questions feel free to send a message.

Regards